# Firestore get a post title using async await

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxtjs

I am trying to get a post title from firestore but somehow I could not figure out how that could be done using async await.

```
async getVideo(id) {
  var self = this;
  const ref = this.$fire.firestore
    .collection("posts")
    .where("ytid", "==", id)
    .orderBy("createdAt", "desc");
  try {
    let post = await ref.get();
    console.log(post.data());
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

I tried to console log post.data() but it says post.data() is not a function.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?  Please edit the question to include you debugging information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [ref.get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get), you will get a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) object.  This object contains zero or more [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) objects that contain the data from the query results.  QuerySnapshot does not have a method called `data()`.  You will have to iterate the documents using the provided API to get the DocumentSnapshots:

```
const qsnapshot = await ref.get();
qsnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    const data = doc.data();
    console.log(data);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving multiple documents, so `post` will be a snapshot of documents which does not have a `data()` method.

You'll need to iterate through the snapshot to access the individual documents.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection for a quick guide or https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html for a full reference of the `QuerySnapshot` type.